# Verifying a signature in Apex

Tags: apex, crypto

The apex crypto class is great but it appears to only be able to sign content. Is there any way to verify a signature in apex? I would expect a Crypto.verify() method but it doesn't appear to exist. I have some device which will be shipping me back a configuration file containing a **signature** and **public key** and I'm at a loss on how to successfully verify this. Was planning on using the SHA1 algorithm.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: Which Algorithm you want to use for Varify the Signature? It may be more helpful to provide you the Solution..

Comment: @Aisha Was planning on using SHA1

Comment: I added some code in my answer may be it help you or ask me if you still have problem with more information of your problem

Comment: Are you able to varify now?

Comment: I don't see how the below example let's me verify a SHA1 signature with a public key that is sent to me

Comment: `RequestString` is the string which you want to send and `secret key` is the `publickey` or any thing in your Account with which you want to Integrate and after that you need to send html request by using `POST` or `GET` method. If you still have problem tell me the site with which you want to integrate i do it by making a dummy Account and send you the working code :)

Comment: You should also follow this link it also have full example for SHA1 with VF page and Controller [http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/23944548-How-to-Integrate-Salesforce-with-Cloudinary-](http://support.cloudinary.com/entries/23944548-How-to-Integrate-Salesforce-with-Cloudinary-)

Comment: @Aisha I would like to verify an incoming signature. So if a sender gives me a signature, public key, and payload, how can I verify it? The examples you have listed appear to be for generating a signature in apex.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem - did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 5):

You must follow the Following link it will be helpful for you to understand the Signature varification in Salesforce Apex.
For `SHA1` you can use the below code snippet:

```
private String getMac(String RequestString, String secretkey) {
String algorithmName = ‘hmacSHA1′; // the other options are: hmacMD5, hmacSHA256, and hmacSHA512
Blob input = Blob.valueOf(RequestString);
Blob signing =Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, input, secretkey);
String str=EncodingUtil.urlEncode(EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signing), ‘UTF-8′);
```

use this str if you want signature in url encode if you want it in `base64encode` form only, then use the below code in place of str:

```
String str=EncodingUtil.base64Encode(signing);
```

For `HMACSHA256` you can use the below code snippet:

```
string timestamp1 = datetime.now().formatGmt('EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z');
String action = 'Action';
String algorithmName = 'HMACSHA256';
Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac(algorithmName, Blob.valueOf(timestamp1),
Blob.valueOf(Secretkey));
String macUrl =EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
```

Use the str/macUrl where you want to use Signature may be it in the header if you use the `POST` method.
For Sha-1 signature in APEX You can follow the below three links:
http://www.tgerm.com/2012/07/sha-1-apex-rackspace-salesforce.html  **AND** 
http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/07/06/using-rsa-sha1-with-salesforce-crypto-class/
 **and** 
http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Apex_Crypto_Class

Comment: **Provide context for links** Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: The context is how to verify when you only have access to the "signature and public key" i.e. not the private key. I don't see that covered in your answer or am I missing something?

Comment: Is there news about the solution ?  I also need to check a signature using the signature and the public key

Answer (score 1):

I got this response on the subject from Salesforce support that confirms there is presently no direct solution in Apex:

> crypto.verify method is not available is salesforce / apex

and that it is necessary to use:

> third party app / external code

So it is necessary to create, deploy and call e.g. a Java Heroku app to get this done. A lot more work than calling an Apex API.

**PS**

Looks like methods have been added - see comment below.

Comment: is this response still valid, as i can see Crypto Class now have a verify() method? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_crypto.htm?search_text=Crypto