# how to verify a PEM-encoded X.509 certificate with Apex

Tags: apex, certification

My REST service hosted on Salesforce receives a http(s) request that headers contain a signature and a SignatureCertChainUrl with which a X.509 certificate can be downed. The certificate consists of public key, algorithm name, etc. How can I verify it with Apex? Is there any Apex library can deal with X.509 type certificate? Any help is appreciated.

updated:

I have read [Verifying a signature in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/verifying-a-signature-in-apex?rq=1) but It does not help.