# How to check a signature using crypto class when you only have access to the "signature and public key" (i.e. not the private key)?

Tags: apex, crypto

In the salesforce there is a function Crypto.sign() that computes a unique digital signature for the input string, using the specified algorithm and the supplied private key.

What I want to do is the reverse , I mean that I want to check if the signature is authentic.
So if I have a public key and the signed data , how can I do to check the authenticity ?

Comment: There is not solution in the question  [Verifying a signature in Apex](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/20945/verifying-a-signature-in-apex) , Their solution is to call an external service to verify the signature, And other replies are incorrect ....  **_The context is how to verify when you only have access to the "signature and public key" i.e. not the private key_** @kurunve

Comment: Well, apparently, question is exactly the same. ANd there are no way how to do it internally in SF